# Get Values from a MAP/any Collection in round - robin fashion

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics, collections, dictionary

I have a static map like this

```
static Map<String, Desttination> myMap = new HashMap<String, Desttination>();
```

Thais have 4 or n key value pair inserted.
....

My requirement is each time when i want to retrieve value from map one by one. For example

When I cal first time like `getValue()` it return the Value for `Key1`

```
Next time it return the Value for Key2
Next time it return the Value for Key3
Next time it return the Value for Key4
```

Next time it return the Value for Key1 Again..

What is the best way to implement this ? Is there Java inbuilt function for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Queue? If the order of retrieval determines what is returned, what is the purpose of the keys?

Comment: Interesting semantics for a `Map`. If you only want the values in a RR fashion, why use a map at all?

Comment: I cannot pass the key....If not Map, what is the best to do it ?

Comment: It depends on how you are adding the entries and using this data structure otherwise. You need to provide much more detail before anyone could give a definitive answer. Right now we would just be guessing.

Comment: There is no java inbuilt function for your requirement. You can try implementing a [Circular Queue](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS3343/rec1/queue.html) data structure for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requriement, you can use a `Queue`. Only things once you populated your Queue, you have to first `poll()` the value from it and after using the value you need to reinsert the value in `Queue` by calling `add()` method.

```
    Queue<String> testQueue = new LinkedList<String>();

    testQueue.add("first");
    testQueue.add("understand");
    testQueue.add("problem");
    testQueue.add("then Ask");
    String fristValue = testQueue.poll();

    //Use your value;
    System.out.println(fristValue);

        //After you are done using it, resubmit it to the Queue
    testQueue.add(fristValue); 

    String secondValue = testQueue.poll();

    //same way....
    System.out.println(secondValue);
```

Replace `String` to your own encapsulated class if your really use `key`. But considering your question, `key` is not as important for you.

Anyways if its important, then your encapsulated class would look like below:

```
 class Entry{
    String key;
    String value;
    .....
   //Relevant methods.
 }
```